# adding page numbers to the output of pdfjam

Tags: number-formatting, pdfjam

I'm using pdfjam to output 2x2 versions of a pdf file.      Is there a way to add page numbers to the output of the reduced pdf.      That is, if I had a 28page pdf, reduced it to 7 2x2 pages, the pages of the reduced file would be 1-7.
Thanks!

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on Stack Overflow.